# Conditional expression exponential equation solving

Tags: equation-solving, conditional

```
Module[
 {
  A = 40 acre, h = 30 ft, por = 0.3, Swi = 0.38, Boi = 1.2,
  pini = 6000 psi, pbubble = 930 psi, rf = 0.23,
  cr = 3*10^-6  1/psi, cw = 2*10 ^ -6 1/psi, co = 5*10^-5 1/psi,
  porvoli, watvoli, OOIP, Np, porvol2, watvol2, Bo2, fmatbal2, soldp2
  },
 (*calculations*)
 porvoli = A*h*por;
 watvoli = porvoli Swi;
 OOIP = porvoli (1 - Swi)/Boi;
 Np = OOIP rf;
 (*functions of depletion*)
 porvol2[dp_] = porvoli Exp[- cr dp];
 watvol2[dp_] = watvoli Exp[+ cw dp];
 Bo2[dp_] = Boi Exp[+ co dp];
 (*material balance equation*)
 fmatbal2[Np_, 
   dp_] = (OOIP - Np) == (porvol2[dp] - watvol2[dp])/ Bo2[dp];
 soldp2 = dp /. Solve[fmatbal2[Np, dp], dp] // First // Simplify;
 Grid[{{"Final pressure calculated by using exponential approximation
is", (pini - soldp2)/psi, "psi"}}, Frame -> All] // nf
 ]
```

Then the results show that:

```
ConditionalExpression[
 0.000145(9.259*10^6-(0.+(4.332*10^10) I) C[1]), C[1] ∈ Integers]
```

Which is not a number result, I run the similiar solve function with linear approximation and it works well, I am a new user of *Mathematica*, I am not sure what does conditionalexpression mean and got stuck here.

Comment: Did you try looking up `ConditionalExpression` in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

1. You did not give us a definition for the function `nf` in your expression, so I left it off.
2. The conditional expression is generated by `Solve` because by default it looks for *complex* solutions, not just real ones. You can ask `Solve` to find only real solutions though: using `Solve[fmatbal2[Np, dp], dp, Reals]` instead of your `Solve` expression. This immediately returns $1343.01\ \text{psi}$ as the final answer, with no `ConditionalExpression`.

Comment: Alternatively, add `/. C[1] -> 0 // Chop` to the end of the `ConditionalExpression`, but your solution is better.